# geom_dotplot with decimal values

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have some troubles with the dotplot function applied on my data.
I could reproduced the problem using diamonds data.
The problem is that some different values are grouped together whereas they shouldn't be.
For example, the two yellow dots ("J") are aligned together whereas one is 64 and the other is 63.8. There is another value 63.8 colored as "E" that is just below. I would like something more accurate according to the value.
It seems that value are rounding and that sometimes these value are separated on several lines.
I don't see the problem on other data (see example 2).

Example 1

```
data("diamonds")
dia=diamonds[1:30,]
dia[order(dia$depth, decreasing = TRUE), ]

 carat       cut color clarity depth table price    x    y    z
9   0.22      Fair     E     VS2  65.1    61   337 3.87 3.78 2.49
11  0.30      Good     J     SI1  64.0    55   339 4.25 4.28 2.73
19  0.30      Good     J     SI1  63.8    56   351 4.23 4.26 2.71
22  0.23 Very Good     E     VS2  63.8    55   352 3.85 3.92 2.48
18  0.30      Good     J     SI1  63.4    54   351 4.23 4.29 2.70
5   0.31      Good     J     SI2  63.3    58   335 4.34 4.35 2.75
21  0.30      Good     I     SI2  63.3    56   351 4.26 4.30 2.71
6   0.24 Very Good     J    VVS2  62.8    57   336 3.94 3.96 2.48
12  0.23     Ideal     J     VS1  62.8    56   340 3.93 3.90 2.46
20  0.30 Very Good     J     SI1  62.7    59   351 4.21 4.27 2.66
27  0.24   Premium     I     VS1  62.5    57   355 3.97 3.94 2.47
4   0.29   Premium     I     VS2  62.4    58   334 4.20 4.23 2.63
7   0.24 Very Good     I    VVS1  62.3    57   336 3.95 3.98 2.47
14  0.31     Ideal     J     SI2  62.2    54   344 4.35 4.37 2.71
28  0.30 Very Good     J     VS2  62.2    57   357 4.28 4.30 2.67
17  0.30     Ideal     I     SI2  62.0    54   348 4.31 4.34 2.68
8   0.26 Very Good     H     SI1  61.9    55   337 4.07 4.11 2.53
1   0.23     Ideal     E     SI2  61.5    55   326 3.95 3.98 2.43
23  0.23 Very Good     H     VS1  61.0    57   353 3.94 3.96 2.41
16  0.32   Premium     E      I1  60.9    58   345 4.38 4.42 2.68
30  0.23 Very Good     F     VS1  60.9    57   357 3.96 3.99 2.42
29  0.23 Very Good     D     VS2  60.5    61   357 3.96 3.97 2.40
13  0.22   Premium     F     SI1  60.4    61   342 3.88 3.84 2.33
26  0.23 Very Good     G    VVS2  60.4    58   354 3.97 4.01 2.41
15  0.20   Premium     E     SI2  60.2    62   345 3.79 3.75 2.27
2   0.21   Premium     E     SI1  59.8    61   326 3.89 3.84 2.31
10  0.23 Very Good     H     VS1  59.4    61   338 4.00 4.05 2.39
24  0.31 Very Good     J     SI1  59.4    62   353 4.39 4.43 2.62
25  0.31 Very Good     J     SI1  58.1    62   353 4.44 4.47 2.59
3   0.23      Good     E     VS1  56.9    65   327 4.05 4.07 2.31
>
```

```
ggplot(dia, aes(y=depth, x="")) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  geom_dotplot(aes(fill=factor(color)), binaxis='y', stackdir='center', dotsize=0.5, stackgroups = TRUE)
```

[image]

With other data (see below) that I created to see better what was happening, the problem doesn't exist anymore

Example 2

```
abb=c(1,1.5,1.5,1.5,2,2,2,2.5,3.5,5,5,5.5,5.5)
bcc=c("Lyon", "Lyon", "Bordeaux", "Bordeaux", "Chambéry", "Lyon", "Lyon", "Nantes", "Nantes", "Lyon", "Lyon", "Rennes", "Lyon")
Fil=data.frame(abb,bcc)

> Fil
   abb      bcc
1  1.0     Lyon
2  1.5     Lyon
3  1.5 Bordeaux
4  1.5 Bordeaux
5  2.0 Chambéry
6  2.0     Lyon
7  2.0     Lyon
8  2.5   Nantes
9  3.5   Nantes
10 5.0     Lyon
11 5.0     Lyon
12 5.5   Rennes
13 5.5     Lyon
```

with dotplot, I the value 5 and 5.5 are group together. I would like the same but with different "lines" for this values

```
ggplot(Fil, aes(y=abb, x="")) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  geom_dotplot(aes(fill=factor(bcc)), binaxis='y', stackdir='center', dotsize=0.5, stackgroups = TRUE) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#FF8000", "#FF0033","#80FF00","#FFFF00", "#000000"))
```

[image]

What are the solution to fix this problem ?

Comment: I tried geom_jitter, but the dot are not well centered as in dotplot, and I prefer this kind of representation.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot, the  ggplot code, I edited my post

Comment: What you mean with lines? The boxplot lines? Or the color of the dots outline?

Comment: "Lines" are line formed by dot aligned together. In my first example, the two yellow dots with the arrow are on a same "line" whereas they don't have exactly the same value (64 and 63.8). And the dot just below is  on a second "line" whereas it has the same value than one of the yellow dot (63.8). I would like to have a "line" by exact value.

Comment: So your second example is what you want and is correct?

Comment: Yes second example is what I want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to change the `binwidth`. Before I changed the `binwidth` I was getting a message from ggplot regarding selecting the `binwidth`. The message I was getting said

> Bin width defaults to 1/30 of the range of the data. Pick better value
> with `binwidth`.

`ggplot2` was telling you that `binwidth` was the issue

```
ggplot(dia, aes(y=depth, x="")) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  geom_dotplot(aes(fill=factor(color)), binaxis='y', stackdir='center', dotsize=0.5, stackgroups = TRUE,binwidth = 0.2)
```

[image: example]

Fixing the bin width is just a bandaid. I think using `geom_jitter` might be a good alternative

Comment: I think you provided the answer, there is here no need for jitter, simply as values never overlay but are already stacked next to each other. The OP needs to set a bin width anyhow just to determine on which line it belongs.

Comment: Thank you ! Changing the bin solved my problems. Indeed I saw this message, but I did not change it by the good way. Could you explain me why this is better to use geom_jitter as I have now what I want ?

Comment: geom_jitter creates some small variation to your data points and is usefull if you have like many exact same values that are plotted on top of each others. But you sometimes just want to see the density of the points. So they are randomly adapted with a small variation value. You do not want nor need a jitter. you want even the opposite, just based on your bin. If they fall in the same bin, your dots do not overlay, but they are stacked from left to right, so no jitter needed.